# JQuery Formatting Issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, concatenation

I can't get this to work for the life of me.  The URL concat messes up.  The answer doesn't seem obvious...

```
function(data){
$('#dataDisplay').prepend("<img src='http://url"+data+"moreurl' />").fadeIn("slow");
});
```

Firebug throws missing end argument errors.

Comment: (X)HTML tag attributes are surrounded by double quotes (`"`). You should replace `src='...'` with `src="..."`. (Recall that you can escape the quote with a backslash.)

Comment: You're right!  Escape (pronounced like Dori would have).  Thanks!

Comment: It's simpler to just single quote the string and use double quotes inside... (instead of escaping).....`.prepend('<img src="ht..` what is `data`?

Comment: HTML and XHTML both accept either `'` or `"` as attribute delimiters. This is quite explicit in the relevant specifications.

Answer (score 0):

```
function xx(data){
$('#dataDisplay').prepend("<img src='http://url"+data+"moreurl' alt='' />").fadeIn("slow");
});
```

you should name your function as XX for example and **i think** you must add the ALT attribute

Comment: Javascript uses anonymous functions. In particular jQuery uses them all over the place in callbacks. The alt tag is nice to have, but it has nothing to do with this issue.

Comment: alt is an attribute, not a tag

Answer (score 0):

Try string replacement using a placeholder instead and stop worrying about escaping.

```
var img = '<img src="http://url{data}moreurl" />';
img = img.replace("{data}", data);
$('#dataDisplay').prepend(img).fadeIn('slow');
```